# Boundary Points of a Plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Why does a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ not possess any boundary points? Isn't the set of points of the plane equal to its boundary set? For instance, for $2x+3y-1=0$, the set of points in $y=(-2x+1)/3$ are itself, boundary points?

Comment: Conclude from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)).

Comment: *Boundary* appears in two contexts:  boundary of a set (intersection of the closure of the set with the closure of its complement), and boundary of a manifold with boundary (e.g., for purposes of applying Stokes's Theorem or the Divergence Theorem). These are different notions. Ordinarily, in a calculus course, only the latter is relevant.

Comment: If $S=${$(x,y)∣x^2+y^2<1$} and    $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ ,
the following set S is not closed, but is it bounded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewed as a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$, a plane is closed and has no interior points, hence is its own boundary.